# Loop through a list of table columns, and apply a query to them

Tags: sql, oracle

We have our table mytable, that contains columns: id, value, description....

Now I want to apply this sql query to each column:

```
select distinct [column] from mytable;
```

Is there a way to do this?

nb. I want to provide the list of columns to loop through, rather than looping through every column in the table.

Comment: You can certainly use dynamic SQL to generate the query.  What is it, though, that you want to do with the results?  And what assumptions can we make (i.e. can we assume that the table always has N columns)?  Do you just want to open three `sys_refcursor` objects that are returned to the caller?  Do you want to do something with the results in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  l_tab_name varchar2(32) := 'MY_TABLE';
begin
  for c1 in (select t.column_name from user_tab_columns t where t.table_name = l_tab_name)
    loop
      execute immediate 'select distinct ' || c1.column_name || ' from ' || l_tab_name;
    end loop;
end;
```