# Oracle PL/SQL finding Max and Min of each column

Tags: sql, oracle

First question on here, thanks for all the responses in advance. I am trying to create a PL/SQL code which will find max and min for each variable in a table. The table is very large about 100+ variables and more than million records.

Edit: I want to create a loop instead of a select statement where I will have to type max and min 100+ times for each column.

Ideally, I was planing to get the column names from the user statistics table with a select statement as variables, then create a loop of select max and min of each one of these variables from the table.

Also, the table has different type of columns. So I also need to find a way to filter out the other types that are not numerical.

Thanks again for all the responses below.

Comment: Welcome to SO.   please read these links ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
http://sscce.org/ ) on how to post a question.  You will get a better outcome that way.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic   Why do you think you need to use PL/SQL instead of just one simple SQL select statement?

Comment: Please note that, I want to create a loop instead of typing max and min 100+ times. And also column names are very different.

Comment: Take a look at the user_tab_columns view and create a dynamic SQL string to execute with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Could you open this a little? Sorry not familiar with dynamic SQL.

Comment: If the column names are going to be static then it is far better to write it out by hand once rather than trying to code something dynamic and incurring a huge (relatively speaking) performance overhead each time it is run.

Comment: @user3105364 You can get an idea of iteration through the list of columns [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460321/loop-through-a-list-of-table-columns-and-apply-a-query-to-them/20478969#20478969).

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav, I think this might help! I will try and see if it works.

Comment: How do you want to manage with different data types ? Number, char, varchar, date, blob etc - columns can have different types.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN( column001 ) AS min_column001,
       MAX( column001 ) AS max_column001,
       MIN( column002 ) AS min_column002,
       MAX( column002 ) AS max_column002,
       MIN( column003 ) AS min_column003,
       MAX( column003 ) AS max_column003,
       MIN( column004 ) AS min_column004,
       MAX( column004 ) AS max_column004,

...

       MIN( column099 ) AS min_column099,
       MAX( column099 ) AS max_column099,
       MIN( column100 ) AS min_column100,
       MAX( column100 ) AS max_column100
FROM   YourTable;
```

Comment: Each column name is different, I want to create a loop where it will just do it for all the column names. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically generate the SQL needed to select all the columns from a table

```
  SELECT 'SELECT '
          || LISTAGG( 'MIN("' || COLUMN_NAME || '") AS "MIN_' || COLUMN_NAME || '"'
                  || ',MAX("' || COLUMN_NAME || '") AS "MAX_' || COLUMN_NAME || '"'
                , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_ID )
          || ' FROM TBL'
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLENAME';
```

Which will then can be copied and run to output the minimum and maximum values for each column.

If you are insistent on doing it all dynamically then (assuming different datatypes for various columns):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb3dc4/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  asdfghjkl NUMBER,
  poiuytrew VARCHAR2(3),
  oiuytrewq DATE,
  sdfghjkla NUMBER,
  zxcvbnmcv NUMBER,
  mnbvcxznb NUMBER,
  qwertyuio NUMBER,
  wertyuiop NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT LEVEL, LPAD( TO_CHAR( LEVEL ), 3, '0' ), TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - LEVEL, LEVEL+1, 10-LEVEL, LEVEL, ABS(5-LEVEL), POWER( 0.9, LEVEL )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;

CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 1 = 0;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb3dc4/1/0)**:

```
| ASDFGHJKL | POIUYTREW |                       OIUYTREWQ | SDFGHJKLA | ZXCVBNMCV | MNBVCXZNB | QWERTYUIO |   WERTYUIOP |
|-----------|-----------|---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
|         1 |       001 | December, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         2 |         9 |         1 |         4 |         0.9 |
|         2 |       002 | December, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         3 |         8 |         2 |         3 |        0.81 |
|         3 |       003 | December, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         4 |         7 |         3 |         2 |       0.729 |
|         4 |       004 | December, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         5 |         6 |         4 |         1 |      0.6561 |
|         5 |       005 | December, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         6 |         5 |         5 |         0 |     0.59049 |
|         6 |       006 | December, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         7 |         4 |         6 |         1 |    0.531441 |
|         7 |       007 | December, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         8 |         3 |         7 |         2 |   0.4782969 |
|         8 |       008 | December, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         9 |         2 |         8 |         3 |  0.43046721 |
|         9 |       009 | December, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        10 |         1 |         9 |         4 | 0.387420489 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE
  min_sql CLOB;
  max_sql CLOB;
  min_rec tbl%ROWTYPE;
  max_rec tbl%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Generate the SQL to find the minimums
  SELECT 'SELECT '
          || LISTAGG( 'MIN("' || COLUMN_NAME || '")', ',' )
                WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_ID )
          || ' FROM TBL'
  INTO   min_sql
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TBL';

  -- Generate the SQL to find the maximums
  SELECT 'SELECT '
          || LISTAGG( 'MAX("' || COLUMN_NAME || '")', ',' )
                WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_ID )
          || ' FROM TBL'
  INTO   max_sql
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TBL';

  -- Execute the SQL to find the minimums and put the
  -- results into a %ROWTYPE record (to ensure dataypes
  -- match).
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE min_sql INTO min_rec;

  -- Execute the SQL to find the maximums and put the
  -- results into a %ROWTYPE record (to ensure dataypes
  -- match).
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE max_sql INTO max_rec;

  -- Do something with the minimums
  INSERT INTO test VALUES min_rec;

  -- Do something with the maximums
  INSERT INTO test VALUES max_rec;
END;
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb3dc4/1/2)**:

```
| ASDFGHJKL | POIUYTREW |                       OIUYTREWQ | SDFGHJKLA | ZXCVBNMCV | MNBVCXZNB | QWERTYUIO |   WERTYUIOP |
|-----------|-----------|---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
|         1 |       001 | December, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         2 |         1 |         1 |         0 | 0.387420489 |
|         9 |       009 | December, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        10 |         9 |         9 |         4 |         0.9 |
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks a lot. 
What would you recommend if I wanted to take out the non-integer columns?

Comment: If you are selecting every column for a table then you can use the same technique regardless of whether you have different or the same data types. If you are selecting a sub-set of the columns of a table then you can create a record with only that sub-set in and build the SQL and `SELECT` or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` into that record. Another alternative if the datatypes are the same is to get the column names from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and run multiple `SELECT ... INTO ...` statements in a `FOR` loop. I would still recommend hard coding the column names rather than using a dynamic query at run time.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to type in all the column names, execute the following query:

```
SELECT 'min('||column_name||'), max('||column_name||'), '
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'myTableName';
```

Then copy the results into a query buffer and construct the rest of the query around it.  That is:

- Add `select` before the first line
- Add `from` whatever table you want
- Remove the last comma

You can also do this just by selecting the column names:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'myTableName';
```

Copying the output into Excel (or your favorite spreadsheet) and using formulas to generate the code.